# How to do -F in PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I have the following curl console commands

```
curl -i -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD https://foo.com/api/metadata/ -F key="url" -F value="http://foo.com"
curl -i -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD https://foo.com/api/queries/ -F image=@/tmp/image.jpg
```

How do I pass the `-F` parameter values in PHP cURL

Comment: might want to look for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option in PHP cURL

Answer (score 2):

Add file in post fields and then use curl like following code:

```
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

**Note:** Use `realpath()` to get file path.

[More details](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/)